# How to do float comparison in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, floating-point

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "Enter the first number: "
read a 

echo "Enter the second number: "
read b

if [ $a -eq $b ]
then 
echo "$a is larger Number"

else
echo "$b is larger Number"
fi
```

Comment: bash numeric variables are ints.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the basic calculator command `bc`?

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "Enter the first number: "
read a
echo "Enter the second number: "
read b

if (( $(echo "$a > $b" |bc -l) )); then
echo "$a is larger Number"
else
echo "$b is larger Number"
fi
```